# Anything going on for a mathematician stuck at New York?

Tags: soft-question, tag-removed

First of all, apologies for the really non-standard question/announcement. I know this is not what MO was intended for, but in this situation it is the easiest way to reach (perhaps) the right person.

On my way back to London from some workshop in Ohio, I got stuck in NYC because of that infamous volcano. No definite news except there is no chance I can get back to Europe before next Friday. I thought I could make something productive with all this time, but have no contact with any mathematicians in any of the Universities nearby.

So, if anybody in NYC or surroundings is interested on hearing about my work (lately mostly about the field with one element, plus some quantum groups and noncommutative geometry stuff), you have the perfect occasion to bring me to your department. For free! I am open to discussions, seminars or in general anything that is going around, if anybody is up, just send an email!

Comment: You offer would be more attractive if you provided your name and a direct link to your bio/proposed talks.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.04.17

Comment: there are worse places to be stuck... you can visit Courant, Columbia, Cuny Grad Center, Stony Brook to name a few.  But - come on - there's a ton of things to do now you have the chance.

Comment: Welcome to New York, although I am sorry to hear about your travel difficulties. I would suggest for you to peruse the CUNY GC seminar listings at http://math.gc.cuny.edu/seminars/seminars.html, and contact the organizers of seminars that might be appropriate.

Comment: Gerhard: Click on his little picture below the message, and find out your information.


Comment: +1, cool question :).

Comment: The question is cute, but the tags are, hmm, strange.

Comment: Thank all for the warms responses!

@Gerhard, all is on my website, that you can see if you click on my name.
@John, sure I'll do all the touristy stuff, but why not to forge some useful work connections now that I got the chance?
@Joel, thanks! Wil give them a look!
@Mariano, hehe, I know, just expected that anybody interested in my work would be interested in those tags and feel curious about them.

Comment: Gerald, I did, and found out more.  If he had put the link in his question, I would have done more towards his offer of accepting his invitation (if I could have.  Not being on the East Coast, I can't do much for him.), and thought I would tell him so.  So I did.

Comment: I changed the tags to something more reasonable. I think that, especially now that this question has been up for a bit, we shouldn't litter in tag searches unnecessarily. @javier: if you feel that you hadn't advertised enough, feel free to revert (but then, fix it after a few days, please).

Comment: @Ilya: no worries, advertised well enough (I actually got as lucky as to be conceded a slot in CUNY). Thanks all for understanding and warm responses.

Answer (score 18):

Just walk into any seminar you find interesting:

http://math.columbia.edu/calendar/main/one/next_week.html

http://www.cims.nyu.edu/events/

http://www.math.poly.edu/news/seminars.phtml

http://math.gc.cuny.edu/seminars/bulletin04_13.pdf

No need to contact anyone in advance. If you need directions on how to get to any of these places, just ask and I'll post them.

ADDED: It's also very easy to do day trips by train to neighboring universities:

http://www.math.sunysb.edu/html/seminars.shtml

http://www.math.rutgers.edu/seminars/calendar.php

http://www.math.princeton.edu/seminars/

https://www.math.upenn.edu/cgi-bin/calendar/view.pl?item=NextWeek

MORE: If you want to *give* a talk instead of listening to one, I suggest you find a seminar where the speaker isn't going to make it from Europe and where the organizers know either you or your work. You could then contact them and offer to be a substitute.

Comment: Also New Haven (Yale) is reasonably close, about the same distance as Philadelphia.

Comment: And the IAS http://math.ias.edu/seminars

Comment: Oops. How could I forget both Yale and IAS? Thanks!

Comment: @Deane: about your last edit, what a fabulous idea! If concert halls can get last minute substitute musicians, why not maths seminars?

Comment: @Deane: +1 again (so to speak) for your addendum.  Definitely a great idea.  

Comment: Thanks for all the links!
Your suggestion sounds great. I just thought that several of the seminar organizers might read the question and reply if they needed a replacement :-)

Comment: Even if you don't give a talk (to be honest, you would be very lucky to set one up), I encourage you to attend a seminar or two and do your best to meet other mathematicians, whether they are in your field or not. Serendipitous encounters like can really pay off.